# ORDER BY RANDOM - With or without replacement?

Tags: sql, random

When using something like `SELECT * FROM Object ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 200`, to randomly sample 200 objects out of a table, is the sampling done *with* or *without* replacement? I am speculating it is *with*, but I don't know for sure. I have not found any documentation about this. I am using SQLite but I don't think the implementation there differs from the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a random value is assigned to all rows, then the topmost 200 are selected, so it is done without replacement since it is impossible for the same row to be selected twice.

Comment: Could you provide me with a source, too?

Comment: What do you mean? an example of db engine implementing this? I can propose a simple experiment: Create a table, add 10 rows (0..9), if random works with replacement, you can construct any sequence of numbers playing with the limit, but as it doesn't you will always get maximum 10 rows, and surprisingly, no value repeated (which has a very low probability if it was random with replacement).

Comment: Of course I could try it out as you say. But it could be implemented in other ways too -- I really wonder whether there is documentation in either one of the SQL standards or at least in some DBMS reference. I have searched exhaustively and found none. That's why I am asking for a source, because how can you be so sure? ;-) Don't get me wrong, I believe in your answer, too.

Comment: I cannot be 100% sure, but I really don't see how it could be inmplementend differently and stil make sense for a rdb engine. Any other possible implementation I can think off actally requires to change how the engine works inside by a lot. And I've played with random and databes a bit. But it's true, I fail to certify that this is how it works without dwelling longer on this problem than I want to. Sorry.